# chrome.app.window resize to smaller dimensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am creating a `chrome.app.window` (on Windows) and it seems that the dimensions of the window cannot be smaller than 130x26px. Is there a way of having a window smaller than 130x26px?

I have already tried with both `resizeTo` and `setBounds` function.

Comment: Are you creating the window with the normal frame, or are you planning to provide your own frame?

Comment: I am planning to provide my own frame, infact I have set the 'frame' option to 'none' in the CreateWindowOptions

Answer (score 1):

This looks like some arbitrary limit in place for the chrome frame windows, which should not be applied for frameless windows. I'm guessing this comes from the API implementation and isn't some limit imposed by Windows.

I've logged https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=224860 to investigate and hopefully fix this, feel free to star it.